# How inject external javascript file in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use this [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/blob/master/dist/NoSleep.js) inside my AngularJs controller. I installed NoSleep using bower but I need to inject it to my angularjs controller, but I have no idea on how do it, NoSleep isn't an angular service and I need to use this declaration `var noSleep = new NoSleep();` in order to use it.

I'm using babel, webpack, gulp, karma

Any advise?

Comment: You'll need to specify your development setup. Are you using webpack? Grunt/Gulp? etc.

Comment: Hi @FranciscoMateo webpack, gulp

Answer (score 2):

Typically when using non-angularjs libraries in an Angularjs application they are wrapped in a module. Then you inject the module into your app and then inject the service/factory you've wrapped with this into your controllers as needed, so you'd create a module that looks something like this:

```
(() => {
  "use strict"
  angular.module('nosleep.module', []).factory('nosleep', ['', function () {
    return new NoSleep()
  }])
})()
```

Then you'd inject the module into your main application module with something like:

```
angular.module('myApp', '[nosleep-module')
```

Then in your controllers that require access to nosleep you'd inject nosleep.

```
class myController {
    constructor(nosleep) {
       this.nosleep = nosleep
    }
}
```

Then from within your control your can address it with `this.nosleep`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any JS lib and it's not an Angularjs lib, just add it using `script` tag in the html file and call it like you used to before they create AngularJs.
Have you tried it ?

Or go to the other way and wrap the lib with AgnularJs service (write an AngularJs service and call the lib method inside it), then inject this new service anywhere you want.

**Update:**
What @Mike Feltman and @richbai90 said in their answers was good and maybe enough for you, but I think it's better to build your service and call a methods you created, but inside these method use what ever library you want (it'll be like using interfaces in C#):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('nosleep.module', []).service('nosleep', ['', nosleepFunc]);

    function nosleepFunc() {
         var nosleepObj = new NoSleep();

         var service = {
              method1: method1,
              method2: method2
              //... etc
         };

         function method1() {
             return nosleepObj.method1();
         }

         // ..... other methods

         return service;
    }

})();
```

This way if you wanted to change `nosleep` lib to another one, and that new one lib has another method names, you need only to change in your service code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like NoSleep just declares a function in the global scope, so you could do something like this:

**NoSleepService.js**

```
(function () {
    // place noSleep minified code here
    angular.module('myApp').service('noSleep', NoSleep);
})()
```

That will create a NoSleep object within the enclosing function so that it doesn't pollute the global scope and register a `new` instance of it to your angular app.